# jQuery Mobile: How to go back one page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

**BACKGROUND**

I am writing an MVC 4 / jQuery Mobile site. I have a `Header.cshtml` shared view defined like this:

```
@model string

<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <a data-rel="back" href="javascript:history.back()">Go back</a>
    <h1>@Model</h1>
    @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", null, new
    {
        data_icon = "home",
        @class = "ui-btn-right jqm-home"
    })
</div>
```

which I call like this:

```
@Html.Partial("Header", "Registration")
```

**PROBLEM**

The above runs fine in my desktop browser, but when I test using Mobilizer (http://www.springbox.com/about/tools/), it seems that `history.back()` does not work on mobiles. So then I thought.. okay, there's always more than 1 way to get things done.. so I tried this:

```
<a data-rel="back" href="@Request.UrlReferrer">Go back</a>
```

Strangely, that doesn't work either and I don't know why. I am guessing that `UrlReferrer` is calling something in the browser and the mobile browser does not support it. Unfortunately, I cannot actually test that theory as Mobilizer does not seem to let me inspect the page source.

In any case, I need a solution.. of course I could stop using this generic shared view and copy-paste it to everywhere instead, but needless to say that would suck... Can anyone tell me how to solve this one, so I can re-use my header code?

**EDIT**

At first I thought @DWolf had solved the problem. But now I see it hasn't.

I have checked and confirmed that Mobilizer is not the problem. I did this by testing a different emulator. In this case, ElectricPlum's iPhone simulator:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SimulatingAnIPhoneOrIPadBrowserForASPNETMobileWebDevelopmentWithWebMatrix2OrVisualStudio2012.aspx

So, `data-add-back-btn="true"` also does not work. It does seem odd though that a built-in function of jQuery Mobile for back buttons does not work... What is that?!?!? HELP!

Comment: Did you try leaving the href attribute blank? Linking to the referrer or history.back() might be breaking data-rel='back'.

Comment: I also recall using "javascript: . . ." in an href to call JavaScript code never worked for me on iPhone's browser.

Comment: @orb, i remember the jquery mobile docs saying to put an href there for C grade browsers.. see here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/pages/page-links.html..so therefore it wouldn't make sense for  the href to be breaking it. but thanks anyway.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

jquery mobile keeps the page cached, so if you flip from page 1 to page 2, it shows page 2, but it keeps on to page 1 behind the scenes

if you add

```
data-add-back-btn="true"
```

to your page

```
<div data-role="page" id="page2" data-add-back-btn="true" >
```

it will go back 1 page

Comment: +1.. not a perfect solution though, because I still have to add it to every page and not only that, the back button doesn't always get rendered.. only within navigation between linked pages ..i.e.  #page2, #page3... etc

Comment: Looks like I jumped the gun on that +1.. I tried it in Mobilizer and it doesn't work.. perhaps Mobilizer has a problem.. I will research it a little more..

Comment: the data-add-back-btn works for jquery mobile, but i wasnt sure about mobilizer.. i assumed it would work since it is a MVC/Jquery Mobile project

Comment: It works in my desktop browser, but not in Mobilizer. Unfortunately, I don't have a modern phone to hand to check it directly. Also check my edit.. I mentioned that it's not only Mobilizer, but ElectricPlum's iPhone simulator is having the same problem.